# Why does `fatrace` not detect certain open events (udisks /dev/sda)?

Tags: linux-kernel

> [Why is `ioerr_cnt` rising, without showing any messages in the log?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/435719/why-is-ioerr-cnt-rising-without-showing-any-messages-in-the-log/)
>
> I'm struggling a bit to work out what process does this. `sudo lsof +D /dev/` doesn't seem to show any processes with a SCSI device currently open, but I don't see any relevant open() calls at the time of the errors either (`cd /dev && sudo fatrace -c`)...
>
> [Answer:] udisks polls drives every ten minutes e.g. for SMART data.
>
> ```
> $ ps -ax|grep udisksd
>   810 ?        Ssl    0:13 /usr/libexec/udisks2/udisksd
> $ sudo strace -t -f -p 810
> [pid   810] 14:11:09 clone(strace: Process 26543 attached
> child_stack=0x7f8fc551ddf0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7f8fc551e9d0, tls=0x7f8fc551e700, child_tidptr=0x7f8fc551e9d0) = 26543
> [pid 26543] 14:11:09 set_robust_list(0x7f8fc551e9e0, 24 <unfinished ...>
> [pid   810] 14:11:09 poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=0}, {fd=9, events=0}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}, {fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 5, 599968 <unfinished ...>
> [pid 26543] 14:11:09 <... set_robust_list resumed> ) = 0
> [pid 26543] 14:11:09 prctl(PR_SET_NAME, "pool") = 0
> [pid 26543] 14:11:09 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/sda", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK) = 14
> [pid 26543] 14:11:09 ioctl(14, SG_IO, {guard='Q', protocol=BSG_PROTOCOL_SCSI, subprotocol=BSG_SUB_PROTOCOL_SCSI_CMD, ...
> ```
>
> I don't know why `fatrace` did not seem to show this device being opened by udisks. It managed to show other device opens (like when I ran lsof, or when I started firefox and it opened /dev/dri/card0).

^ Does anybody know?

Comment: does the `fanotify(7)` example code compiled an run against the `/dev` directory show any activity?

Comment: That one seems _completely_ silent, it doesn't show firefox opening  `/dev/dri` even though `fatrace -c` at the same time does.  However, I worded my original complaint wrong.  `fatrace` only seems to show firefox opening `/dev/dri`, and not the actual device node `/dev/dri/card0`.  Similarly, `fatrace` doesn't show anything for `cat /dev/null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `fatrace` does not show *any* device opens.  You can use it to see processes opening *directories* under `/dev`, like `/dev/dri`, but not device nodes like `/dev/dri/card0`.