# Double dots in kern.log

Tags: linux-kernel, rsyslog

The `kern.log` in an embedded ARM linux system with the kernel 3.10.104 contains a lot of messages:

```
2019-06-24T14:13:43.056996+00:00 localhost kernel: ..
2019-06-24T14:13:43.596996+00:00 localhost kernel: ..
2019-06-24T14:13:44.067000+00:00 localhost kernel: ..
2019-06-24T14:13:44.606997+00:00 localhost kernel: ..
2019-06-24T14:13:45.076994+00:00 localhost kernel: ..
```

What does it mean and how can I identify the source of these messages?

EDIT:

The logging daemon is `rsyslogd 8.30.0`. The related configuration for kern.log is just:

```
kern.*            /var/log/kern.log;RSYSLOG_FileFormat
```

Comment: In theory userspace programs can write messages to [/dev/kmsg](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/dev-kmsg). However e.g. `journalctl` logs under systemd do not show a "kernel: " prefix for messages written by userspace.  Just to be sure, I think it would be useful to edit to specify the name and version of logging daemon you are using.

Comment: ok, logging daemon info added to the question

Comment: @sourcejedi I Suspect that.How can journald tell the difference between kernel written messages and userspce written to /dev/kmsg?

Comment: May be your suspection is correct. Any idea how to find application that is writing to the /dev/kmsg and poluting kern.log?

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 "It is not possible to inject messages from userspace with the facility number LOG_KERN (0), to make sure that the origin of the messages can always be reliably determined." The question I have in mind, is whether the logging daemon makes sure only to add the "kernel: " prefix for LOG_KERN lines, or if it does not check and adds the prefix for all lines read from `/dev/kmsg`.

Comment: `lsof` or `fuser` (or looking at the links in /proc/*/fd/) can find processes which have currently opened /dev/kmsg.  It is harder if it opens and closes /dev/kmsg each time though, e.g. "echo foo > /dev/kmsg".  I think ["fatrace" can't track device node opens](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/435760/why-does-fatrace-not-detect-certain-open-events-udisks-dev-sda).  If you have a good kernel tracing setup, you could probably trace device opens by the device number, but you might not have all the necessary debug symbols or stuff...

Comment: I did further investigation. I have not find any user space application that opens /dev/kmsg. I think the messages is related to iscsi. The kern.log does not contain these messages after reboot and they begins when I execute `iscsiadm -m discover ...` or `iscsiadm -m node ...`. However they are not written by iscsiadm.